# How to set value in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working on Nodejs project and would like to set specific value. Can you please help me to make it work ?

```
function myFunction(args){
 var v = args['key'];
 v.replace('c', 'customer');
 return args; //return args with the new value of args['key']
}
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on "to set specific value"?

Comment: `string.replace()` returns a new value, it doesn't change the existing value. You'll have to update the value of `args['key']` to the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
function myFunction(args){
  args['key'] = args['key'].replace('c', 'customer');
  return args; 
}
```